# Chances of getting Flint

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When i find gravel, i always break it, place it, break it and repeat these steps till I get Flint.

So what are the chances of getting a flint from gravel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a block of gravel is mined, there is a 10% chance that a single piece of flint will drop instead of the gravel block. When mined with a Fortune-enchanted tool, this chance is increased to 14% at Fortune I, 25% at Fortune II, and 100% at Fortune III.

- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Flint
  Hope this answers your question

Comment: What about when dropped on a block like a torch? Does that count as being mined?

Comment: On the wiki page for [gravel](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Gravel), it states that it always drops as gravel if it falls on "a non-solid block, (such as torches, slabs, rails, or redstone) or soulsand," so you'll never get flint that way.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ The always-gravel drop is to prevent flint farms.